# Should the wort be boiled?

Tags: techniques

We bought a hard root beer kit--we are new to this--a friend says not to boil, the kit has boiling instructions.  Is it necessary to boil to make beer?

Comment: What sort of kit is it - what is supplied and what do the manufacturers instructions say? Is this a yeast based kit or a "wild ferment" or a lactobacillius based kit or what? One presumes that the end user can't go that far wrong by following the instructions supplied but it is difficult to say unless more details are forthcoming.

Comment: Who do trust more, the people who made the kit, or your friend?

Comment: NB: Its a ROOT BEER KIT not a beer kit/

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instructions.

Not all adjuncts are suitable for "no boil" brew.

Adjuncts could have microbes that may be dormant without oxygen and need the boil to kill them.

Also the recipe may need some boil off to get the OG right.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time wort is boiled. It sanitizes the beer, creates reactions that affects the flavour and helps with hop isomerization.

There are exceptions, but there aren't many.

Rather follow the instructions. We can only assume that the company that made the product wishes you to have the best possible product.